# Product of two Hermitian matrices

Tags: matrices, hermitian-matrices

According to Wikipedia:

> The product of two Hermitian matrices $A$ and $B$ is Hermitian if and only
>   if $AB = BA$.

So if I understood correctly, if $C=AB$, then C will be Hermitian if and only if $AB=BA$.

But... I've been able to create a matrix $S$ then did $R=SS^H$, and $R$ turned out to be Hermitian, even though $SS^H \neq S^HS$.

So I'm clearly misunderstanding that property I quoted. Could anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: $H$ is Hermitian **iff** $H=H^*$. If $(AB)^* \neq AB$ then clearly, by definition, $AB$ is not Hermitian. Unless $S$ is Hermitian, your example is irrelevant.

Comment: Note the fifth word in the wikipedia quote

Comment: For the proof of the claim in Wikipedia, recall that $(AB)^\ast=B^\ast A^\ast$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $S^HS$ is **not** the adjoint of $SS^H$. The adjoint of $SS^H$ is always $SS^H$, whatever $S$ is. In your example, your $S$ is not hermitian, so the commutation of hermitian matrices does not apply.